# Arrowhead as MeshStyle or PlotMarkers for ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to use the `Meshstyle` option of the `PlotMarkers` option in `ListLinePlot` to have `Arrowheads` as a point marker, obviously pointing in the positive direction of the line at that point? Using the example below, what sort of function would I need in the `MeshStyle` option.

```
ListLinePlot[Range[10]^2]
```

If not, what alternative solution might exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quite simple solution is to replace the `Line` directives with `Arrow`. Sine there is usually only *one `Line` directive*, you have to partition the list of points manually:

```
ListLinePlot[Range[10]^2] /.  Line[pts_] :> (Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Aha! Now to go and learn about RuleDelayed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> *what sort of function would I need in the `MeshStyle` option*

You can place arrows on the line using `Mesh`, `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading` options:

```
ListLinePlot[Sin@Range[0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/50], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> 6, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  MeshShading -> {Arrowheads[Medium]}, DataRange -> {0, 4 Pi}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Using

```
MeshShading -> {Directive[Arrowheads[Small], Dotted, Red], 
  Directive[Arrowheads[Medium], Blue]}
```

we get

[image]

Using different setting for `MeshFunctions`:

```
ListLinePlot[Range[-10, 10]^2, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
  Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  MeshShading -> {Arrowheads[Medium]}, DataRange -> {-10, 10}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For function plotting:

```
f[x_] := x^2; (* define a function to plot *)
df = 1/4; (* define a step size for the arrows *)

g[x_] := Sin[x];
dg = Pi/16;

{
 Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Epilog -> Table[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[3],
     Arrow[{{i - df, f[i - df]}, {i + df, f[i + df]}}]
     }, {i, -5, 5, 2 df}], ImageSize -> 300],
 Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Epilog -> Table[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[3],
     Arrow[{{i - dg, g[i - dg]}, {i + dg, g[i + dg]}}]
     }, {i, 0, 6 Pi, 2 dg}], ImageSize -> 300]
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
ListLinePlot[Range[10]^2]/.Line[x__]:>{Arrowheads[Table[.05,10]],Arrow[x]}
```

[image]