# Arrowheads on parametric curves

Tags: plotting, animation

I have the following animated parametric curve where the gap looks like it's rotating in the counterclockwise direction.

```
Animate[ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, a, a + 2 Pi - Pi/8}, 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

I'd like to add an arrow to the endpoint so that is appears to point in the direction of rotation. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: After the `ParametricPlot[]`, try adding a `/. Line -> Arrow`…

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, can you answer your own question, please? :) Thanks.

Comment: Duplicates: [(13547)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13547/121),
[(55535)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55535/121),
[(60838)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60838/121).  More examples: [(4793)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4793/121),
[(38350)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38350/121),
[(43478)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43478/121),
[(48882)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48882/121),
[(59340)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59340/121),
[(73314)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73314/121).

Comment: As well as [(2099)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2099) and this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71843

Answer (score 2):

```
Animate[ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, a, a + 2 Pi - Pi/8}, 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}] /. Line -> Arrow, {a,0,10}]
```

[image]